# doctrine error service not found

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm

Just came from an error on Symfony when trying to generate a new entity,
service doctrine is not found, `[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException]

  You have requested a non-existent service "doctrine"`
Further DB system is MongoDB and is configured in config.yml

```
doctrine_mongodb:
connections:
    default:   
        server: mongodb://localhost:27017
        options: {}
default_database: social
document_managers:
    default:
        auto_mapping: true
```

Comment: How are you attempting to generate a new entity?

Comment: Sorry, i mean by console. I just created database and indexes